# 404 Not Found when viewing tag page for [r.java]

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, hyperlinks, 404-not-found

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please prevent creation of tags that could trigger the IIS file extension filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128965/please-prevent-creation-of-tags-that-could-trigger-the-iis-file-extension-filter)

There’s a tag on SO [[r.java]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r.java) (created by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085959/no-generated-r-java-file-in-my-project)) that can’t be browsed — the server just returns an empty 404 page.

Comment: The same happens with the [asp.net] tag.

Comment: @ChrisF: No, you **can** browse (visit) the tag page for [asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) but **not** for [r.java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r.java)

Comment: @Jonas - it didn't use to be the case - I can't find the reference though. Obviously the same fix needs applying in the [r.java] case.

Comment: @ChrisF: Ok, I understand. However, see my answer below, I have renamed the tag to `[r.java-file]`.

Comment: @Jonas - I did see, however it would be better to implement a generic solution.

Answer (score 9):

this is a file extension issue. ASP.NET is refusing to serve a *.java file - same as if you wanted to check the tag soapi.cs on stackapps.

I have covered this in another post over on stackapps - [What's the difference between tags soapi.cs and soapi.js to get a bug triggered by the former?](https://stackapps.com/questions/1380/)

There are some very simple ways to handle this, but the issue has not gotten much attention.

A workaround, posited by systempuntoout, is to append an underscore, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r.java_ , as padding that will be converted to space and subsequently trimmed off AFTER the request gets past ASP.NET.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the underscore-workaround. I decided to rename the tag to `[r.java-file]` because of this issue, but I was struggling to find  all questions that used the tag since I couldn't see the tag-page. But with this workaround I could re-tag them all.

Answer (score 2):

I created the `[r.java]` tag because `R.java` is a specific auto-generated file in Android projects. Many people is having problem with this file so a tag is helpful.

I didn't know this issue with `*.java` files/URIs. But I recongniced it myself a few days ago, when I clicked on the tag.

Now I have renamed the tag to [`[r.java-file]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r.java-file) which works better. I have also retagged the other few questions that used the `[r.java]` tag.