# Please prevent creation of tags that could trigger the IIS file extension filter

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

Someone created [user32.dll](/questions/tagged/user32.dll) the other day.  Being a dutiful member of the New Tag Deletionist Cabal, I dove in to try and see if there could be a better, existing tag for the question, only to be greeted with nothing.  The server returned 404, a Date header, and a content length of zero.

This is a [known behavior with IIS that has bit SO before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69379/404-not-found-when-viewing-tag-page-for-r-java).

Given that this is known IIS behavior, the tagging system should make an effort to block users from creating new tags that will result in the site breaking.

<sup>(As for [user32.dll](/questions/tagged/user32.dll), I was able to find the question and replace the tag with [user32](/questions/tagged/user32))</sup>

Comment: Isn't the real solution to not have them trigger the filter to begin with? Not sure what kind of problems are involved with that, but it makes sense to me.

Comment: Since this can be fixed (supposedly) when we move to MVC v4, it seems like this would be for a short-term benefit.  I think it's better to wait and see if we can take care of all these extensions *and* use those valid tag names.

Comment: Interesting.  When will you know whether or not it can be fixed with the move to MVC 4?  Rather, will you be playing with the beta, or is this something that would be looked into only after it's out of beta?

Comment: @Charles - Let me say this: "maybe".  Stack Overflow itself was created with the first beta of ASP.Net MVC...so who knows.  It's not a top priority at the moment, we have other major things behind the scenes that are first up.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136767/how-to-display-questions-tagged-by-dll-tags

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After the next build we will allow extensions that were previously restricted.  We have updated to ASP.NET MVC4 and it appears to handle them correctly.