# How to display questions tagged by .dll tags?

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please prevent creation of tags that could trigger the IIS file extension filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128965/please-prevent-creation-of-tags-that-could-trigger-the-iis-file-extension-filter)

How do I display questions related for the following tags ?
[bass.dll](/questions/tagged/bass.dll)
[msvcr90.dll](/questions/tagged/msvcr90.dll)
[msvcr90d.dll](/questions/tagged/msvcr90d.dll)
[ieframe.dll](/questions/tagged/ieframe.dll)
[mscorwks.dll](/questions/tagged/mscorwks.dll)
[shell32.dll](/questions/tagged/shell32.dll)
[scilexer.dll](/questions/tagged/scilexer.dll)
[.dll](/questions/tagged/.dll)

My problem is that in none of the well known browsers (Firefox, IE or Chrome) I have tried this on I wasn't able to display related questions for them (because of some kind of security block or expected dll file ?)

P.S. I did that because I've been looking for some unanswered question related to Scintilla (Scilexer.dll) but here I get stucked:

[image]

So far I found this at [.dll](/questions/tagged/.dll) tags; the other *file or extension tags* like for instance [.exe](/questions/tagged/.exe), [.ocx](/questions/tagged/.ocx) works fine.

Comment: So it would be great if the links from the tags would end by the `/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what was causing the problem (it happens for me too), but there is a very simple workaround.

If you have a tag URL such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scilexer.dll simply add a slash to the end of the URL, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scilexer.dll/

In Firefox, Chrome, and Safari, at least, this will make the browser interpret the URL as a folder rather than a file, and so it will display correctly. I have not tested it in IE or Opera.

Comment: D'oh, that's what I haven't think about. Thanks! +1, accept and bounty (in 22 hours) is yours ;-) However it's interesting that for the other extensions those browsers works. They evidently don't like `*.dll`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a famous bug about URL's ending in .dll in Microsoft's web server, no?

Comment: Might be, I haven't met this before (because as I remember I've never downloaded standalone dll file), but is that really the reason why Firefox and Chrome (at least those I've tried) protects against that ? One thing I would suggest in this case is to add the slash to the end of the links going from the tags. Thanks for the post anyway, but it feels more like a comment to me ;-)

Comment: It's on the server side, not the client side.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. So it's not a browsers problem but the Stack's server side. Sorry, I'm really lame to this stuff, I'm a desktop app maniac, but good to know this :-)