# Bug when searching for wildcards in tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, wildcards

I am trying to search for `[jquery-*]` so I type that into the search bar:

[image: part uno]

And then I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image: nada]

### What happened?

Instead of going to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-*
It went to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-

Which displays **no results**, but yet still has the `jQuery` tag wiki.

The same things happens when you search for other tag wildcards as well.

---

This was ***supposedly*** fixed: [Searching for a tag containing * breaks the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1649/155556) (**but** I guess not to the fullest extent of the law....)

---

Related: [Add ability to use wildcarded tags in search](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/3383)

Comment: Hmm, that would likely explain [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136767/how-to-display-questions-tagged-by-dll-tags).

Comment: @TimStone no that has always been an issue. it has to do with ASP and its extensions. Can't put `.dll` at the end of the URL

Comment: No, the issue there is that search throws out the `*` and synonimizes [tag:.dll] to [tag:dll], and is unrelated to the problem you're describing (that problem is why that synonymn exists, however)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems to me that this works as expected now.

Comment: Oops, fixed this a few weeks ago, missed some metas it looks like